# How do I upgrade from Windows 10 1803 to 1809? I'm getting a failure 0x80070003

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

When attempting to upgrade from Windows 10 1803 to 1809, I get a failure every time. I tried Microsoft support and three reps were unable to assist me. I tried disabling all the startup programs, running the update troubleshooting tool, running Windows 10 update assistant, and downloading / installing from a USB drive. The result is consistently failure with the logs below:

setuperr.log

```
2019-02-22 19:32:40, Error                 MOUPG  CFCDCATQuery::RetrieveResponse(311): Result = 0x80072EE7[gle=0x00002ee7]
2019-02-22 19:32:40, Error                 MOUPG  CFCDCATQuery::Query(210): Result = 0x80072EE7[gle=0x00002ee7]
2019-02-22 19:32:40, Error                 MOUPG  CFCAcquirerDCAT::QueryWeb(653): Result = 0x80072EE7
2019-02-22 19:32:40, Error                 MOUPG  CFCAcquirerDCAT::Download(878): Result = 0x80072EE7
2019-02-22 19:32:40, Error                 MOUPG  CFCPayloadDU::Download(267): Result = 0x80072EE7
2019-02-22 19:32:40, Error                 MOUPG  DUSetup: Error on downloading SetupDU Payload: [0x80072EE7]
2019-02-22 19:32:40, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionDU::ExecuteFacilitatorDUSetup(2159): Result = 0x80072EE7
﻿2019-02-22 19:32:56, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:32:56, Error                 SP     pDUSearchAndDownload: DU search failed. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:32:56, Error                 MOUPG  DUSetup: Failed to execute DUSetup seach and download  [0x80240438]
2019-02-22 19:32:56, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::IsMeteredConnection (188):   Failed to get NetworkCostType assuming metered network [0x80004005].[gle=0x80004005]
2019-02-22 19:33:36, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::Utilities::SendRequest (1363):   Failed to connect to the internet or send request: [12007].[gle=0x80072ee7]
2019-02-22 19:33:36, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::Utilities::DownloadCabFile (4292):   Failed to send request using default proxy[gle=0x80072ee7]
2019-02-22 19:34:16, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::Utilities::SendRequest (1363):   Failed to connect to the internet or send request: [12007].[gle=0x80072ee7]
2019-02-22 19:34:16, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::Utilities::DownloadCabFile (4303):   Failed to send request using auto proxy[gle=0x80072ee7]
2019-02-22 19:34:16, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::Utilities::DownloadAndExtractCab (4094):   Failed to download cab file: [0x80072ee7].[gle=0x80072ee7]
2019-02-22 19:34:16, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::GetAlternateData (2982):   Error downloading alternate cab http://adl.windows.com/appraiseradl/2019_01_31_04_51_x64.cab: [0x80072ee7].[gle=0x80072ee7]
2019-02-22 19:34:16, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::InitializeRunOptions (757):   Error checking for latest SDB, swallowing: [0x80072ee7].[gle=0x80072ee7]
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 MOUPG  CFCDCATQuery::RetrieveResponse(311): Result = 0x80072EE7[gle=0x00002ee7]
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 MOUPG  CFCDCATQuery::Query(210): Result = 0x80072EE7[gle=0x00002ee7]
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 MOUPG  CFCAcquirerDCAT::QueryWeb(653): Result = 0x80072EE7
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 MOUPG  CFCAcquirerDCAT::Download(878): Result = 0x80072EE7
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 MOUPG  CFCPayloadDU::Download(267): Result = 0x80072EE7
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Error on downloading ImageDU Payload: [0x80072EE7]
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionDU::ExecuteFacilitatorDUImage(1465): Result = 0x80072EE7
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #38# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = a34 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup'), vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-02-22 19:37:18, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #37# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:31]'\Registry\Machine\SYSTEM\Setup\', vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-02-22 19:37:19, Error                 CSI    00000003 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #70# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = 9c4 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts'), vn = [l:21 ml:22]'Arial Nova (TrueType)', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-02-22 19:37:19, Error                 CSI    00000004 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #69# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:69]'\Registry\Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts\', vn = [l:21 ml:22]'Arial Nova (TrueType)', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2019-02-22 19:37:27, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:37:27, Error                 SP     CDownloadDUUpdates::DoExecuteInternal: Failed to search for updates. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:37:27, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: Failed to download updates. Error: 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:37:27, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute critical search and download [0x80240438]
2019-02-22 19:37:36, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:37:36, Error                 SP     CDownloadDUUpdates::DoExecuteInternal: Failed to search for updates. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:37:36, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: Failed to download updates. Error: 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:37:36, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute GDR search and download [0x80240438]
2019-02-22 19:37:36, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to set WU internal configuration property for targeted scans. hr = 0x80070057
2019-02-22 19:37:45, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:37:53, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:01, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:10, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:10, Error                 SP     CDownloadDUUpdates::DoExecuteInternal: Failed to search for updates. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:10, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: Failed to download updates. Error: 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:10, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute driver search and download [0x80240438]
2019-02-22 19:38:18, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:18, Error                 SP     CDownloadDUUpdates::DoExecuteInternal: Failed to search for updates. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:18, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: Failed to download updates. Error: 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:18, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute FOD search and download [0x80240438]
2019-02-22 19:38:27, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to end the asynchronus search. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:27, Error                 SP     CDownloadDUUpdates::DoExecuteInternal: Failed to search for updates. hr = 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:27, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: Failed to download updates. Error: 0x80240438
2019-02-22 19:38:27, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute LangPack search and download [0x80240438]
2019-02-22 19:38:36, Error                 CONX   0xd0000034 Failed to add user mode driver [%SystemRoot%\system32\DRIVERS\UMDF\uicciso.dll]

2019-02-22 19:41:01, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2019-02-22 19:41:25, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #95107# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216, status = '(null)', value = { type: 40972, bytes ( 12 ): 65006e002d00550053000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-02-22 19:41:40, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #177818# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216, status = '(null)', value = { type: 40972, bytes ( 12 ): 65006e002d00550053000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-02-22 19:41:52, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                 SP     CMountWIM::DoExecute: Failed to mount WIM file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\winre.wim. Error 0x80070003[gle=0x00000003]
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Mount WIM file C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\winre.wim, index 1 to C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount. Error: 0x80070003[gle=0x000000b7]
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Failed execution phase Pre-Finalize. Error: 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: ExecuteCurrentOperations reported failure!
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Using action error code: [0x80070003]
2019-02-22 19:43:40, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionPreFinalize::ExecuteRoutine(545): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Execute(441): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteAction(3259): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteActions(3413): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Execute(1644): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2478): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2441): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(883): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(390): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:41, Error                 SP     CDeploymentBase::CleanupMounts: Unable to unmount the directory C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SafeOS\SafeOS.Mount. Error: 0xC142011C[gle=0xc142011c]
2019-02-22 19:43:42, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(282): Result = 0x80070003
2019-02-22 19:43:42, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(400): Result = 0x80070003
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1196114/trying-to-update-windows-10-to-1703-error-code-0x80070003-0x20009